# how to play only one popup onclick link on jsp page

Tags: javascript, jsp

Javascript file

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function voddisplay(a,b) { 
            `document.getElementById(b).innerHTML="<embed type='application/x`-`shockwave-flash' src='flash/player.swf' width='500' height='400' allowscriptaccess='always'` allowfullscreen='true' `flashvars='file="+a+"&image=preview.jpg&autostart=true'/>";`
        }
 </script>
```

My JSP page

```
<%
    arr_pubitr = arr_public.iterator();
     int myvaluep=0;
     while(arr_pubitr.hasNext()){
     pb = arr_pubitr.next();
     String url = "http://ar.fun2shoot.com/"+pb.getContent_id()+".flv";
    myvaluep++;
 %>
    <div class="rightdata">
<a href="javascript:void(0);" style="text-decoration: none;" 
    `onclick="return hs.htmlExpand(this , { width: 510, objectWidth: 510, objectHeight:`  `465,height: 465}),voddisplay('<%=url%>', 'abc<%=myvaluep%>')"  class="playbtn">preview </a>`

<div class="highslide-maincontent">
 <div id="abc<%=myvaluep%>" class="buyme"></div>Loading Please... Wait</div>
<div>
  <img src="<%=pb.getPreview() %>"  title ="<%=pb.getTitle() %>"/>`enter code here`
    <input style="margin-top: 5px;" type="checkbox"  name="video_cont"  value="<%=pb.getContent_id() %>"/>
     <%=pb.getView_count() %> views
     </div>
</div>
```

need only one popup  for different different  link play

Comment: add a javascript tag to it...

Comment: this code also javascript tag inside